# Lazy loading with Linqjs and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to consume the Enumerable at the knockout databinding stage?
I have only got it to work if I first do ToArray, which will consume the Enumerable

http://jsfiddle.net/xZmWx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own foreach variant to work with Enumerables.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['foreach2'] = {
    makeTemplateValueAccessor: function(valueAccessor) {
        return function() {
            var bindingValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

            if (bindingValue instanceof Enumerable) {
                bindingValue = bindingValue.ToArray();
            }

            // If bindingValue is the array, just pass it on its own
            if ((!bindingValue) || typeof bindingValue.length == "number")
                return { 'foreach': bindingValue, 'templateEngine': ko.nativeTemplateEngine.instance };

            // If bindingValue.data is the array, preserve all relevant options
            return {
                'foreach': bindingValue['data'],
                'includeDestroyed': bindingValue['includeDestroyed'],
                'afterAdd': bindingValue['afterAdd'],
                'beforeRemove': bindingValue['beforeRemove'],
                'afterRender': bindingValue['afterRender'],
                'templateEngine': ko.nativeTemplateEngine.instance
            };
        };
    },
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['init'](element, ko.bindingHandlers['foreach2'].makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor));
    },
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers['template']['update'](element, ko.bindingHandlers['foreach2'].makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/QeEQg/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Youre still doing ToArrray which will consume the Enumerable, so its not true Lazy, you will still iterate over the Enumerable 2N times, if it was true lazy it would have been N times